# Datatables ajax request not working with xhr but with local json file

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm using a static .json file to load a table during testing. This works fine with the following controller code:

```js
 function dashboardResearchPubCtrl($scope, $http, dataService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dtInstance = {};
          vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        "url": "/api/research-pub.json",
        "type": "GET",
        "data": function ( d ) {
            return JSON.stringify(d);
        }
    })
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withOption('filter', false)
    .withOption('fnPreDrawCallback', function () {
        $("#overlay").show();
    })
    .withOption('fnDrawCallback', function () {
        $("#overlay").hide();
    })
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('content_id').withTitle('Id'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('content_title').withTitle('Title')
      ];
 }
```

However, if I change the url from "url": "/api/research-pub.json" (a local .json file) to  "url": "/api/research-pub" (the xhr endpoint (which renders the same json as the file), then datatables load the data, but instead I get the datatables warning alert message: table_id=dataTable Datatables warning: Requested unknown parameter for id 'content_id'... Chrome network shows the xhr response data, but nothing shows up in datatables.

Is there a parameter I need to add or remove to get the xhr working? Thanks!

This is the view code:

```html
<div ng-controller="dashboardResearchPubCtrl as vm">
    <table id="dataTable" datatable="" dt-instance="vm.dtInstance" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable"></table>
 </div>
```

and json response:

```json
[[{"rating_cnt":140,"rating_avg":4,"content_id":"122","content_title":"Business-Driven Dealer Training","content_metadata":null,"access_level":"Member","industry":"Automotive","audience_level":"Intermediate","publish_date":"2007-01-24T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"rating_cnt":350,"rating_avg":4,"content_id":"100","content_title":"HR Training & Assessment","content_metadata":null,"access_level":"Member","industry":"Aerospace","audience_level":"Beginner","publish_date":"2014-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"}
]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues :

- The `data()` callback should be `dataSrc()`
- You have a JSON not following dataTables [parameter paradigm](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc)
- Why `JSON.stringify()`..? It does not make sense
- I believe `.withOption('serverSide', true)` is a mistake since the JSON not support it

Returning `d[0]` in `dataSrc()` since the response is on the form `[[{},{}..]` will work :

```js
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('ajax', {
    url: "/api/research-pub.json",
    dataSrc: function ( d ) {
      return d[0]  
    }
  })
  ...
```

The OP code in a demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/tHpb3wQbJtxikxnHrWre?p=preview**

If `serverSide: true` not is required, I would recommend using a promise instead :

```js
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  $http.get('/api/research-pub.json').then(function(result) {
    defer.resolve(result.data[0]);
  });
  return defer.promise;
})
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Both your plnkr examples worked and have been helpful. The myjson.com reference is also very helpful and will help in the future to quickly test ajax requests and xhr endpoints.

Comment: David, is there any easy way to add a date filter on the publish_date column that takes a to and from date? e.g. where publish_date >= $('#startDate').val() && publish_date <= $('#endDate').val()